# Integrating non-ancestor branch into trunk

Tags: svn

When SVN was set up, instead of creating a branch from trunk, we simply created a new folder in the root structure:

```
/branches/dev/  
/trunk
```

and worked on that. Now, of course, it's impossible to merge dev into trunk as SVN doesn't see a hierarchical connection. I'm trying to find the best way to make it proper, so that the dev branch we have our code in is related to trunk and we can do normal merges in the future.

I found two approaches - one of them simply copy code from dev to trunk, commit trunk, and then do a proper branch checkout. My problem with this approach is that we'd lose all the revision history, as the real dev branch would start out fresh.

Other approach is to use --ignore-hierarchy. This seems like forcing stuff into trunk and I'm unsure of the downsides of this approach.

Basically what's the best way to fix the screw-up from the beginning, when we physically created dev folder on our own, instead of branching trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you merge that branch into trunk?

There are different ways to maintain branches and the like inside subversion (and every other rcs). What you intuitively set up is the traditional way: you create folders and copy differences between folders revisions between branches/trunk/tags. That works, since to svn a node in the hierarchy is nothing but a folder. There is no special magic in svn.

Subversion is nothing but a file system with an additional time axis.

So all you have to do is merge the changes (revisions) you committed to the branch node into the trunk:

```
svn merge -r <start>:<current> https://<server>/<repo>/<path>/branches/dev <trunk-checkout>
```

(That is: if your branch initially contained some revision of the trunk. But I assume it did, since you did not say otherwise. If it is completely independent from the trunk then why is it called a branch? And: more important: why do you want to merge it into the trunk?)

---

Update 2013-01-26:

Discussion revealed that the situation involved an empty trunk, never populated and never used, so nothing to merge any changes from a branch into. Instead the whole development originated and was made in something *called* a 'branch' which in reality served as the sole 'trunk' for this project.

So the solution appears like this: 
In this case simply move what is currently called branch to be the projects trunk and continue development under that new (and better fitting) name. Developments are done either inside new checkouts or by rebasing existing checkouts. Branches should from now on be used the way described below. So correct the missfitting names and adjust the current situation so that it matches the typical wording of projects:

- trunk is where the 'main' line of development is done or consolidated
- trunk is where develpment from within branches is re-merged into again
- several branches might be created by forking the trunk at a given point in time

  - inside those branches complex development can be implemented alongside other changes to he trunk without interfering
  - when those more complex developments are done and the new features or architecture got stable ("is ready"), then the changes from a branch can be merged back into the trunk

Comment: when I try the classic svn merge, I get a lot of tree conflicts even though my trunk is completely empty. Almost all root directories in dev branch are marked as C. I thought it was clear from my question that branch did not contain a revision of the trunk. We created an account in Assembla, and went on and created directory branches/dev/ and started working in it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that: you claim your branch does not contain a previous revision of trunk, but you don't say WHAT it contained. So how do you expect an answer? What is the idea of creating a _branch_ of something if you don't start of with that something? Next you claim that _trunk_ is empty. How do you want to merge revisions into something empty? Why is trunk empty if it aparently was not empty before, when you created the branch? And, above all: how can you get conflicts in the _branch_, when you are merging into the _trunk_?

Comment: I do say what it contained: our work. "What is the idea of creating a branch of something if you don't start of with that something? " - Well obviously we made a mistake, that's the entire point of the question. "How do you want to merge revisions into something empty?" Well if branch the trunk when it's still empty, then you would merge the work into an empty trunk. "Why is trunk empty if it aparently was not empty before" How did you get this idea? "how can you get conflicts in the branch" If I knew that I would not be asking the question

Comment: Ok, about the conflicts in the branch: the way you used the merge command must have gone completely wrong. Delete that checkout, it is fruitless to try to reconstruct what went wrong. If the trunk really is empty, then where is the problem? Simply copy the branches content into the trunk and all is fine... No need to merge in that case. you could even move that branch, since it never was a parallel development, so in fact that branch is your real trunk.

Comment: basically yes, dev "branch" is my trunk. I'll look more into the moving stuff you suggested. thanks for the idea.

Comment: I fixed this by svn deleting trunk, svn moving branches/dev to /trunk, and then doing svn copy of trunk to new branches/dev. Can you please ammend your answer so that it revolves around svn move solution? so I can accept it

Comment: I tried to update the answer with a condensed description of situation and actions to be taken.